# Can't clear UIWebView cache

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview

I can't seem to find a way to clear UIWebView cache. I have tried the following, but nothin worked so far:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever];

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:_request];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
_request = nil;

[NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:t_url 
             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData 
// also tried NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData and NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
             timeoutInterval:10.0];
[_request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData];
[_request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil; // Actually never gets called
}
```

Anybody came across this? Thanks!

Comment: did you solved it? i am also can't solve that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have tried almost everything. I'm aware you are rejecting the cookies. Yet, Why dont you try this? This worked for me...

```
   NSHTTPCookie *aCookie;
    for (aCookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:aCookie];
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. It's still cached.